# PHP RegEx Capture with Single Quotes

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm trying to capture from the following string:

```
var MyCode = "jdgsrtjd";
var ProductId = 'PX49EZ482H';
var TempPath = 'Media/Pos/';
```

What I'd like to get is the variable length value between the single quoted ProductId value

```
PX49EX482H
```

I had this, and I think it is close, but the single quotes are tripping me up. I'm not sure how to escape them properly.

```
preg_match('/var ProductID ='(.*?)';/', $str, $matches);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `"` in place of `'` this way you need not escape the `'` found in the pattern:

```
preg_match("/var ProductID ='(.*?)';/", $str, $matches);
```

Also the pattern you are looking for `var ProductID ='(.*?)';` does not match your input string because:

- there is no space after `=`
- `ProductID` does not match `ProductId`

To fix 1, you can give a space after `=`. If you don't know the number of spaces you can use `\s*` for arbitrary space.

To fix 2, you can make the match case insensitive by using the `i` modifier.

```
preg_match("/var ProductID\s*=\s*'(.*?)';/i", $str, $matches);
                          ^^  ^^          ^
```

Comment: You missed a space after equal sign.

Comment: +1 I'm too literal; I only read the "how do you escape single quotes" and completely ignored his real question, "why doesn't this regex work" :p

Comment: Doh! I had the double quotes before but it wasn't working, and it was actually because of the inconsistencies you mentioned. Working now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Characters are escaped within strings in PHP (and virtually all C-syntax languages) with backslashes:

```
'This is a string which contains \'single\' quotes';
"This is a \"double\" quoted string";
```

In your example:

```
preg_match('/var ProductID =\'(.*?)\';/', $str, $matches);
```

Note that you don't have to escape single quotes in a double quoted string:

```
preg_match("/var ProductID ='(.*?)';/", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, but I made a mistake irrelevant to the escapes. You got me on the right track though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/var ProductID = \'(.*?)\';/im', $str, $matches);
```